# Why QWebkit doesn't resolve file:// and qrc:// when used in -webkit-scrollbar css?

Tags: css, webkit, background-image, scrollbars, qwebkit

Example #1:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background-image: url(file:///tmp/bg.png);
}
```

Example #2:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background-image: url(qrc://bg.png);
}
```

Above examples are working only when QWebPage shows local html page. For http://stackoverflow.com it doesn't work. I've set the style using QWebSettings::setUserStyleSheetUrl() - it's a user style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start Chrome (I'm assuming that's the browser you're using) with the command line flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`, or else it won't dynamically load local files (using the file:// protocol), as this could be a big security risk.

You can see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4197&can=1&q=allow-file-access-from-files&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS for a complete history of this flag, why it behaves like this and why it#s implemented like this.

Comment: I'm using Webkit through QWebKit. I can't find any informations about allow-file-access-from-files in Qt documentation. This works as expected: body { background-image: url(file:///tmp/bg.png); }, so it looks like this is enabled by default in QWebKit.

Comment: Yes, image starting with http:// will be loaded without problems. I've found QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls in Qt documentation, and I can confirm - it is enabled by default.

Comment: Have you finally found why?

Comment: No, sadly, I have not :-(

Comment: looks like the qrc reference is missing the third forward slash.